# Will my data be affected if the GUI of Ubuntu crashes?

Tags: gui, desktop-environments

I would like to do some simulation research on Ubuntu (previously I was working on Windows), the simulation data are extremely important to me and I would never want to lose any of them. But I heard that the GUI would crash sometimes, will it affect my data?

Thanks!

Comment: The only way to ensure important data is not lost is to back it up frequently. Worring about rumors of GUI crashes seems to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if there is volatile data relevant to an application that would ultimately fail as a result of your GUI failing, but mainly no.

AKA if your GUI fails and a text editor is open and the text editor dies after the GUID dies
Then you lose whatever was unsaved in the text editor.

Basically no.

Answer (score 1):

Just backup. No, your data should not be affected by GUI crashes, but if you really want to be safe, backup, backup, backup.

Answer (score 1):

This depends largely on how you are managing your data, and what you mean by GUI. If you use a database and you are working with that in a GUI and the GUI crashes (which honestly, I wouldn't worry too much about) then whatever has been updated/changed in your database will be found in the same state as you left it at the moment of said crash. However, as mentioned before, if you are using a text editor or spreadsheet or something like that, you will return to whatever you had the last time you saved the document.

There is a huge difference between using a database and a document to manage data but if you are doing simulations then I think you know that and suspect you are using a database. In that case, there's nothing to fear if for some reason whatever GUI you are using crashes.